# How do you determine how much does an object accelerate by gravity

Tags: acceleration

Ok, so say i have an object that has a mass of **1kg** and it "pulled" by a planet, i know the F = GmM/r^2 thing, but it gives newtons. How do i know how much the object accelerates towards the planet in for example meters?

Comment: "Newtons" are a measure of force, not acceleration. And acceleration is measured in meters per second per second (or meter per squared second), not in meters. I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: You simply leave the small m out of it. Per equivalence principle (which is already built into the formula for Newtonian gravity) you get $a_{gravity} = GM/r^2$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the force in Newtons just divide it by the mass in kg and you get your acceleration in m/sek².